# Image encryption IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, encryption, xor

I am using a double strength XOR encryption to encrypt a bytearray of an image and than rewrite the array into the image file. When I use small numbers for the encryption keys this works great and the file is unreadable until it's run through the code with the same keys, decrypting it. However, I want to use 256-bit keys for protection and anytime I generate these keys and attempt the XOR my function exception runs and I get an index overflow error like this- IndexError: list index out of range

I assume the encrypted bytes are too big for the image file, any way I can fix this?

```
#Encryption/decryption keys
key1 = random.randrange(1, 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336)
key2 = random.randrange(1, 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336)
#In the extraordinarily rare case that both keys are equal regenerate key2
while(key1 == key2):
    key2 = random.randrange(1, 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336)

def secureImg(name):
    try:
        #Path to image
        path = name+".jpg"    
        #Open file to read
        file = open(path, "rb")          
        #Storing image data
        image = file.read()
        file.close()       
        #Converting image into byte array to perform encryption on numeric data
        image = bytearray(image)     
        #Performing XOR operation on each value of bytearray
        for index, values in enumerate(image):
            image[index] = (values ^ key1) ^ key2     
        #Opening file to write
        file = open(path, "wb")          
        #Writing encrypted data in image
        file.write(image)
        file.close()            
    except Exception:
        print("Img error caught: ", Exception.__name__)
```

Comment: is it practical or hypothetical? There are multiple issues in this code, besides proper xoring

Comment: @Marat it is an early stage of a future practical application. Currently the focus is getting everything working before cleaning things up. All suggestions for better code are encouraged, but a solution to the issue is preferred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main issues:

1. Xor is not aligned on chunks. single byte from `image` is being xored with a potentially very long number - the result is unlikely to be one byte.
2. Xor is a commutative operation. There is no reason to use two keys - it is the same as using one, `key1 ^ key2`.
3. Images tend to have a lot of predictable bytes in the header, which makes possible to reconstruct the key

Smaller items: use context managers (`with ...`), don't blanket try-catch, etc.

So, ignoring all conceptual issues it'd be something like:

```
from itertools import repeat
import os

KEY_SIZE = 1024

key = os.urandom(KEY_SIZE)


def bogus_encrypt(name):
    path = name+".jpg"
    with open(path, 'rb') as fh:
        # generally, bad idea; better limit to reasonable increments, few Kb to Mb
        raw_data = fh.read()

    encrypted_data = b''.join(a^b for a, b in zip(raw_data, repeat(key)))

    with open(path, 'wb') as fh:
        fh.write(encrypted_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Marat's idea, reading in the entire file to encrypt is not necessary, you can operate on individual chunks:

```py
from itertools import repeat
from functools import partial
import os

KEY_SIZE = 1024

key = os.urandom(KEY_SIZE)


def bogus_encrypt(name):
    path = f"{name}.jpg"

    with open(path, 'rb') as infile, open(f'encrypted_{name}.jpg', 'wb') as outfile:
        # create a .read() function that takes no arguments
        reader = partial(infile.read, 2**20) # 2**20 bytes is 1Mb

        # iter can be used on a function that takes no
        # arguments, the second arg is a sentinel value
        # telling the loop to stop
        for chunk in iter(reader, b''):
            encrypted = b''.join(a^b for a, b in zip(chunk, repeat(key)))
            # write the chunk to new file
            outfile.write(encrypted)
```